# MongoDB aggregate ERROR('cant $subtract a date from a string')

Tags: mongodb, aggregation-framework

- I'm implementing a requirement to group by time and query the maximum values within each grouping,
  but mongoDB returns an error

```
db.getCollection('Power').aggregate([
     {$match:{
        iotId:"57141305840d8ea11f13",
        createdTime: {'$gte': ISODate("2020-03-11T00:00:00Z")  ,'$lt':ISODate("2021-03-12T00:00:00Z")}
    }},
    {$group: {
        _id: {
            $subtract: [
                { $subtract: [ "$createdTime", new Date("1970-01-01") ] },
                { $mod: [
                    { $subtract: [ "$createdTime", new Date("1970-01-01") ] },
                    1000 * 60 * 5 
                ]}
            ]
        },
        Power: {'$max': '$Power'},
        timelist: { '$push': '$createdTime'} 
  }},
    {$project: {
            timelist: 1
    }}
]
)
```

Comment: It is just the way you have to represent fields in an aggregation pipeline operation - you cannot use `"createdTime"` as a _string_, it is to be used as a _field_ as it is a result of the previous pipeline stage. So, prefix it with a  `$`, and use it ( and the quotes are still required).

Comment: Thanks four your help, this answer is very useful.The error disappeared, but the database returned results that I didn't want. How can I modify it to get the maximum value?

Comment: You can include a sample document from the collection you are querying from - and tell what is it you are trying on the document fields.

Comment: MongoDB stores dates as milliseconds since 1970-01-01T00:00.  What is the purpose of subtracting the zero date from the timestamp?